About $k$-colorable simple graphs
Let $G$ be a simple connected graph which is $k$-colorable and not $k-1$-colorable. And $u, v$ two vertices that are not adjacent.
Is there a $k$-coloring of $G$ in which $u$ and $v$ have different colors?

That depends on $G, k, u, v$. Can you find examples both ways?

Further to @JeanAbouSamra’s invitation, I suggest you consider what is necessary for a graph to be 2-colorable.

Let us consider graphs of order more than $k$ ? Every k-colorable graph is $k+1$-colorable isn’t it? Is there an easy example to understand this? That two non adjacent vertices must have different colors necessarily.

I saw the problem with the question and I corrected it now. I m asking about the optimal coloring only. @PaulTanenbaum

@JeanAbouSamra does the question make sense now?

In other words you are asking, if $G$ is a connected simple graph which is $k$-colorable, and you add a new edge $uv$, is the new graph still $k$-colorable? If that were true, then every connected graph on $n$ vertices would have the same chromatic number as the complete graph $K_n$. Maybe you can find a very small counterexample. The smallest connected simple graph which is not complete has $3$ vertices and $2$ edges.

@user14111 it is not what I am asking, what I am asking is if you know that G is k colorable and not k-1 colorable, and I tell you that u and v are non adjacent, can you conclude that they will always have the same color in any k-coloring of G ?

If $G$ is the graph with vertices $u$, $x$, $y$, $v$ and edges $ux$, $xy$, $yv$, then $G$ is $2$-colorable and not $1$-colorable. The vertices $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent, and they do not have the same color in any $2$-coloring of $G$.

Consider the cycle $C_{2q}$ for $q\geq 2$. It is 2-colorable (and not 1-colorable). Let $v$ and $w$ be the two neighbors of some vertex $u$ in $C_{2q}$ and add the edge $vw$. Then the resulting graph has an odd cycle induced by $u$, $v$, and $w$, so this graph is not 2-colorable.
